# How to convert html table to a csv file python?

Tags: python, html

[image]

I have a python script like this: I can login in to web with my login and password, but i need to convert html table to csv.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


login_url = 'myurl'
data = {
    '_username': 'myusername',
    '_password': 'mypassvord'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post(login_url , data)
    index_page = s.get('myurl/link')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(index_page.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    print(index_page)
    table = soup.findAll("table class", {"class": "table hover"})
    print(table)
```

`Print(index_page)` return Response[200] so it´s OK.

But I want to conert html table to CSV file.

```
 table = soup.find_all("table class", {"class": "table hover"})
```

returns []

[image]

Where I am doing wrong?

I can't get a table from HTML.

Comment: `"table class"` should just be `"table"`. Why did you put `class` in there?

Comment: It would be more useful for others to help you by providing the HTML as text (formatted as code) rather than an image. The two images also appear to be the same.